# How do you know how many mobile devices are connected to Exchange server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

I wanted to know how many of mobile devices, such as iPhone or Android or iPad are connected to exchange server? Is there a script or something I can run?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 4):

You've got a couple of options.

A short and sweet PowerShell one-liner for Exchange 2007 and 2010, like the one below, will show you devices w/ ActiveSync device partnerships, bounded by the date of last contact:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | ForEach {Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:$_.Identity} | Where {$_.LastSuccessSync -gt '11/1/2012'}
```

You also have the new [Get-ActiveSyncDevice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335068.aspx) and [Get-MobileDevice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218706(v=exchg.150).aspx) cmdlets in Exchange 2010 and 2013, respectively.

You don't mention your version of Exchange, however, and the command above will only work on E2K7 and newer. For Exchange 2003 you're pretty much stuck parsing IIS logs. There's some good discussion on the Exchange Team blog [about using LogParser to get a list of devices](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/02/14/419562.aspx).

Comment: when I run Get-ActiveSyncDevice , it got bunch of devices, it doesn't tell me how many it has. whould there be another way to get just the number of the device, like only list the id of the device and see how many lines it printed.

Comment: Read-up on the "Measure-Object" cmdlet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176900.aspx

Comment: thanks man, used measure-object IsValid and got number of devices, but still not sure how to get the most valid device yet

Comment: What do you mean by "most valid"?

Comment: Hi Evan, last sync time is less than 1 week or so

Comment: Have you considered using the one-liner I provided and changing the date range to suit your needs?

Comment: I did that , just came up Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executing. Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently. error. not sure exactly what it means.